# Modelling 1D cylindrical heat flow with constant heat flux and convective heat loss at boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve for temperature $T(s,t)$ in a long uniform cylinder, radius $R$. The cylinder has constant external heat flux $q$ supplied at its surface, and experiences convective heat loss at a rate directly proportional to the difference in surface temperature and atmospheric temperature (which is assumed to be constant at $T_0$).

$s$ is used for distance from symmetry axis of cylinder. The following PDE is obtained, with boundary conditions as follows.

$\frac 1s \frac{\partial}{\partial s} (s \frac{\partial T}{\partial s}) = \frac 1\alpha \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$

$T(s,0) = T_0$ for all $s$. (Condition 1)

$-k \frac{\partial T}{\partial s}|_{s=R} = q + h[T_0 - T(R,t)]$ (Condition 2)

$\alpha$ is a constant (thermal diffusivity), $k$ is the thermal conductivity of the cylinder, $h$ is the convective heat transfer coefficient.

I attempted to separate variables and obtained two ODEs. One yielded an exponential and the other gave a Bessel function. After superposing solutions, I was unable to proceed after getting bogged down in the mess of coefficients.

Can anyone provide guidance in solving the above PDE? Thank you.